# Setting camera position after scene transitions

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

In Cesium Sandcastle app, I edited Camera tutorial to include the code snippet below:

```
window.scene = scene;
scene.morphComplete.addEventListener(function (){
    console.log('Morph completed...');
    var west = Cesium.Math.toRadians(10);
    var east = Cesium.Math.toRadians(40);
    var south = Cesium.Math.toRadians(35);
    var north = Cesium.Math.toRadians(45);
    var rectangle = new Cesium.Rectangle(west,south,east,north);    
    window.scene.camera.viewRectangle(rectangle);
    console.log('Camera view rectangle updated...');    
});
```

The above code hooks to the morph complete event and as soon as the scene transition is completed, view rectangle is set to a region in Europe. At least this is my expected behavior.
The observed behaviour is after morph is completed, Cesium view rectangle is in overseas. My question is how can I set map view rectangle after scene transitions?

Comment: What is the purpose of `windows.scene = scene`? You could just use `scene` instead of `windows.scene` in the event handler... But still I have the same problem, it correctly logs the messages but the camera position doesn't change it is the default (for 3D view) somewhere in the Caribbean sea. Same for you? Or are you in a position different from the default and the one you expect?

Comment: window.scene is redundant you're right. Yes somewhere in the Caribbean sean in my end, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in our camera handling, apparently we set the camera one last time after firing the `morphComplete` event.

You can work around it by waiting for one animation frame to pass before taking control of the camera yourself.  For example:

```
scene.morphComplete.addEventListener(function (){
    Cesium.requestAnimationFrame(function() {   // This is the workaround.
        console.log('Morph completed...');
        var west = Cesium.Math.toRadians(10);
        var east = Cesium.Math.toRadians(40);
        var south = Cesium.Math.toRadians(35);
        var north = Cesium.Math.toRadians(45);
        var rectangle = new Cesium.Rectangle(west,south,east,north);
        window.scene.camera.viewRectangle(rectangle);
        console.log('Camera view rectangle updated...');
    });
});
```

I just filed [Issue #2203](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/2203) for this.